# Installing 2 files in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, updates

I'm attempting to silently install IBM i access and a service pack for it. However due to the nature of how IBM made it, I have to install Windows C++ Security Update x64 & x86 whenever it installs the 64bit version.

I have a batch file that will install either or based on system type, but I'm not able to get it to install one after the other for the 64-bit version.

Here's my code - note some things are commented out for the sake of testing.

```
::@echo off
::Check bitness, proceed accordingly
If exist "C:\Program Files (x86)" GOTO X64

::Setup i Access for 32-bit
:X32

cd %~dp0MS05SU
start /wait msiexec /i vcredist_x86.msi /qn /norestart
cd ..
cd install
cd image32
setup.exe /S
goto END
::Setup i Access for 64-bit
:X64

cd %~dp0MS05SU
start /wait msiexec /i vcredist_x64.msi /qn /norestart
start /wait msiexec /i vcredist_x86.msi /qn /norestart <--- not installing after the above does.
cd ..
cd install
cd image64a
setup.exe /S

:END
::exit
```

The batch file works just fine, I just need both of those updates installed for the 64-bit version.

Anyone know of how I can get both of these to install respectively?

EDIT 1: These are .exe files! That mistake is mine.

Comment: Remove the "start /wait" (3 places). No need to start another window.

Comment: The first mistake is `If exist "C:\Program Files (x86)" GOTO X64` as the program files directory for 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows can be also on a different drive and can have even a different name. Better use `if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" goto X64`. The environment variable with name `ProgramFiles(x86)` is predefined only by 64-bit Windows.

Comment: The second not good written code is twice the command line `cd %~dp0MS05SU`. This command fails if the current directory is on drive C: but the batch file is located on any other drive. Better use `cd /D "%~dp0MS05SU"` which fails only if the batch file is on a network share opened using a UNC path. Best would be the usage of `pushd "%~dp0MS05SU"` working even for UNC paths as long as command extensions are enabled as by default. Run in a command prompt window `cd /?` and `pushd` for help on those two commands.

Comment: Next the 3 `cd` commands before running `setup.exe` can be combined to single command `cd ..\install\image32` respectively `cd ..\install\image64a`.

Comment: Your batch code should also take into account that the specific redistributable package you are installing with this batch file is already installed or even a newer version is installed. For example don't install `Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.17` if there is installed already `Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161` which is fully compatible to build 17, but contains important security fixes.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks so much for all the input you have given. I'm currently working on those edits and trying a few other things. I did want mention that these are .exe files. That was a mistake on my part. Any additional input is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a file issue. I had the wrong file. Was able to extract the actual msi from the exe and boom. Worked.